# How to disable CSRF antiforgery in Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to disable CSRF checks when I'm running under the TestServer so I don't have to read and send the token when running automated tests.

Due to the abundance of "helpful magic" creeping into ASP.NET Core I am stuck.

There's nothing in the template code that obviously adds this, and yet looking at the filters in the debugger during this `services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters)` call shows no global filter.

This code also does not work.

```
mvcOptions.Filters.Add<IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute>(0);
```

And the `Antiforgery.Options` does not have a disable option.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(o =>
{
    o.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
});
```

You can also ignore it at the PageModel:

```
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 1001)]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
```

> Regarding the the Order parameter: The built in [ValidateAntiforgeryToken]
>   decorator has an order of 1000, therefore setting
>   [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken] to 1001 will override it.